# Public key from private key generation problem

Tags: private-key, public-key, ecdsa

I met some problems, when I was trying to write function able to create Bitcoin public key from private key. I was using the tutorial: http://procbits.com/2013/08/27/generating-a-bitcoin-address-with-javascript ---> "Public key" part is most important.

Part of my code looks like this:

```
public String generatePublicKey(String privateKey)
{
    BigInteger privKey = new BigInteger(privateKey,16);
    X9ECParameters ecp = SECNamedCurves.getByName("secp256k1");
    ECPoint curvePt = ecp.getG().multiply(privKey);
    BigInteger x = curvePt.getXCoord().toBigInteger();
    BigInteger y = curvePt.getYCoord().toBigInteger();
    byte[] xBytes = this.removeSignByte(x.toByteArray());
    byte[] yBytes = this.removeSignByte(y.toByteArray());
    byte[] pubKeyBytes = new byte[65];
    pubKeyBytes[0] = new Byte("04");
    System.arraycopy(xBytes,0, pubKeyBytes, 1, xBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(yBytes, 0, pubKeyBytes, 33, yBytes.length);
    return this.bytesToHex(pubKeyBytes);}
```

There are also two functions:

```
final protected static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

private byte[] removeSignByte(byte[] arr)
{
    if(arr.length==33)
    {
        byte[] newArr = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(arr, 1, newArr, 0, newArr.length);
        return newArr;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

However I used bytesToHex() earlier and there weren't any problems. So the thing is that generatePublicKey() does not work properly. I tried to insert private key known from bitcoin wiki:

18E14A7B6A307F426A94F8114701E7C8E774E7F9A47E2C2035DB29A206321725

(from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses)

It should create long public key (even before all hashing) - step 2 on wiki:

0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6

Unfortunately the answer is wrong. Could you Guys look at this and point my mistakes?

Ofc, programming language is Java and cryptographic provider was Bouncy Castle.

EDIT:
I accidentally solved my problem. When I was writing this function, Eclipse told me function getX() (and getY()) is depracated. So I used getXCoord(), because I thought its result is the same. In feeling hopeless I used getX() instead getXCoord() and whole function magically worked!

What's the difference between getX() and getXCoord() ?

Comment: Did you take a look at how bitcoinj does this?

Comment: For the difference between `getX()` and `getXCoord()`, you could look at [the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/bouncycastle/+/master/bcprov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/math/ec/ECPoint.java).  The difference seems to be "normalization", whatever that may be.

Comment: You should really say in the first few sentences of your question what language you are writing your code in, and what libraries you are using to do the ECDSA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally solved my problem. When I was writing this function, Eclipse told me function getX() (and getY()) is depracated. So I used getXCoord(), because I thought its result is the same. In feeling hopeless I used getX() instead getXCoord() and whole function magically worked!

What's the difference between getX() and getXCoord() ?

Comment: The last question would likely get a good answer at stackoverflow.