# Standard CLI tool to calculate a public key out of a private key

Tags: private-key, public-key, cli

Is there a standard, or at least well-accepted, CLI tool that calculates the public key out of a private key?

I've done my homework erading [How do you get a Bitcoin Public Key from a Private Key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25024/how-do-you-get-a-bitcoin-public-key-from-a-private-key), but it's from May 2014, and hopefully tooling has improved since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no standard CLI utility.
However, there are some tools which seem to be generally accepted, like [bitcoin-bash-tools](https://github.com/grondilu/bitcoin-bash-tools)

Alternatively, you can use some script library, such as [pycoin](https://github.com/pycoin/pycoin) (written in Python), or [bitcoinjs](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib%20%22bitcoinjs%22%20(written%20in%20Javascript)).

Personally I like [Bitcore](https://bitcore.io/api/lib/) libraries (Bitcore is not Bitcoin Core, despite their names are similar). They are also written in Javascript.
I wrote a simple library for handling keys/addresses that can be used from the command line with the NodeJS interpreter: https://github.com/frz-dev/btcutils/blob/master/bitcore-keys-utils.js. In your case you can use the `getPubKey` function, passing the private key object.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are few CLI utilies that allow you this:

- [sx](https://github.com/Bobalot/sx) : command line Bitcoin to empower the sysadmin

  cat *key*| sx pubkey
- [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools) : SImple, common-sense Bitcoin-themed Python ECC library

  pybtctool privtopub *key*

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `pip3 install btc-address-dump`

Here is an example:

```
$ btc_address_dump c7ac679b56f50bfd54dd924fe45a8dca7a1c2dced254b03dac22afc03adb9127
private key (hex) = c7ac679b56f50bfd54dd924fe45a8dca7a1c2dced254b03dac22afc03adb9127
private key (WIF) = 5KLDyKtrScLYsKMJzVCt8Mf6Nn9DEV7V3fg8njfSZnqe7ZEMqzK
private key (WIF compressed) = L3urFcPsE2yHf5zeQjVSfUB8j8FEzX5cnmhjNsJfqjKgowPP4tmg
public key (uncompressed) = 044cd0aaeca3b636078583408e75edd77307b5190ca7a48bb9fbc1f2576c17dff1087190d91e26af594e3f8ecd3f4d3596c03c45d3b235da916903c930c6593cc4
public key (compressed) = 024cd0aaeca3b636078583408e75edd77307b5190ca7a48bb9fbc1f2576c17dff1
legacy address (p2pkh uncompressed) = 1Q5RqZctfcNkTPad2tuJSREByd2gB8xs63
legacy address (p2pkh compressed) = 12W36tm2jnreFiYdrzfE6cvRaKRbicEpnA
p2sh-segwit address (p2sh p2wpkh) = 3AzXxVUqdzvzEqVmdtmeVqRwc98uqwyh76
bech32 address (p2wpkh) = bc1qzp6lz6zy9p7k68r0a7lzfpkdxvj3yapynzuatt
```

This tool also support mnemonic words:

```
$ btc_address_dump "olympic wine chicken argue unaware bundle tunnel grid spider slot spell need"
mnemonic = olympic wine chicken argue unaware bundle tunnel grid spider slot spell need
private key (hex) = c7ac679b56f50bfd54dd924fe45a8dca7a1c2dced254b03dac22afc03adb9127
private key (WIF) = 5KLDyKtrScLYsKMJzVCt8Mf6Nn9DEV7V3fg8njfSZnqe7ZEMqzK
private key (WIF compressed) = L3urFcPsE2yHf5zeQjVSfUB8j8FEzX5cnmhjNsJfqjKgowPP4tmg
public key (uncompressed) = 044cd0aaeca3b636078583408e75edd77307b5190ca7a48bb9fbc1f2576c17dff1087190d91e26af594e3f8ecd3f4d3596c03c45d3b235da916903c930c6593cc4
public key (compressed) = 024cd0aaeca3b636078583408e75edd77307b5190ca7a48bb9fbc1f2576c17dff1
legacy address (p2pkh uncompressed) = 1Q5RqZctfcNkTPad2tuJSREByd2gB8xs63
legacy address (p2pkh compressed) = 12W36tm2jnreFiYdrzfE6cvRaKRbicEpnA
p2sh-segwit address (p2sh p2wpkh) = 3AzXxVUqdzvzEqVmdtmeVqRwc98uqwyh76
bech32 address (p2wpkh) = bc1qzp6lz6zy9p7k68r0a7lzfpkdxvj3yapynzuatt
```

Comment: Caution. This is a post by a new user, promoting new software.