# How genereate pub key from priv key ? algo

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

How to generate pub key from prive key ?
All examples and explain skip this.
but i dont need steps to address etc .
i only need steps from priv to pub ( compressed or not )
what using at that.
if possible example or python , or simple algo what used.
example i hv priv key `981F3AF336E23EEFF4384A939065C4C623E394F1AE7E4D922C045CEDC3F258D2`
i want make from them pub key , (i not need generation priv key i have them!)
compressed or uncompressed .
what steps i need to do for make valid public key for bitcoin address .

Update
sorry for my qustion , i cannot undestand this logic.
i try make pub key  as example with 04 uncompresed from priv key 0x64hex, i not need steps for make it base58.
i stuck at that step.
as example
i hv some words i make from them hex 0x64digits.
how i can do from them not public key as example
049f35c793522be1fdcfd50c3fb15f455cda37fb3fb779b9e4707c89a49cdf47242c3dc34778f7361a44c074a6a21e5972bbf5ca5265c9ea121ce4f2a5dc4964b6

Comment: Does [How do you get a Bitcoin Public Key from a Private Key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/29880/5406) answer your question?

Comment: I just tried to fix the grammar, spelling and punctuation, but the question is a bit jumbled. In the first part it seems to me that you say you don't need instructions to get to an address, but then in the last sentence you say "what steps i need to do for make public key for bitcoin address"? Could you clarify the scope of your question please?

Comment: sorry for my qustion , i cannot undestand this logic.
i try make pub key  as example with 04 uncompresed from priv key 0x64hex, i not need steps for make it base58.
i stuck at that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private key used in the example: `a84860187211d36cddfb77fc7638c996b8b8a77d3e16f2e47a5172fe6e8e2be6`

**Converting Private Key to WIF** (Ruby)

```
require 'digest'

# Checksums use hash256 (where data is hashed twice through sha256)
def hash256(hex)
    binary = [hex].pack("H*")
    hash1 = Digest::SHA256.digest(binary)
    hash2 = Digest::SHA256.digest(hash1)
    result = hash2.unpack("H*")[0]
    return result
end

def checksum(hex)
  hash = hash256(hex) # Hash the data through SHA256 twice
  return hash[0...8]  # Return the first 4 bytes (8 characters)
end

def base58_encode(hex)
  @chars = %w[
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
    A B C D E F G H   J K L M N   P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
    a b c d e f g h i j k   m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
]
  @base = @chars.length

  i = hex.to_i(16)
  buffer = String.new

  while i > 0
    remainder = i % @base
    i = i / @base
    buffer = @chars[remainder] + buffer
  end

  #! Is it just the 00, or does 05 get converted to 3, etc.
  # add '1's to the start based on number of leading bytes of zeros
  leading_zero_bytes = (hex.match(/^([0]+)/) ? $1 : '').size / 2

  ("1"*leading_zero_bytes) + buffer
end


# Convert Private Key to WIF
privatekey = "a84860187211d36cddfb77fc7638c996b8b8a77d3e16f2e47a5172fe6e8e2be6"
extended = "80" + privatekey + "01"
extendedchecksum = extended + checksum(extended)
wif = base58_encode(extendedchecksum)

puts wif
```

**Get Public Key from WIF** (Python)

```
from bitcoinutils.setup import setup
from bitcoinutils.keys import PrivateKey, PublicKey

def main():
    # setup the network
    setup('mainnet')

    # existing WIF key
    priv = PrivateKey.from_wif('L2rq82XD1P9bwnyithBaRYn7v91WxRCSraTrfbu6g86VLYsnCmbt')


    # get the public key
    pub = priv.get_public_key()

    # compressed public key
    print("Public key:", pub.to_hex(compressed=True))

if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Source:

https://github.com/in3rsha/learnmeabitcoin-code/blob/master/keygenerator.rb

https://github.com/karask/python-bitcoin-utils/blob/master/examples/keys_addresses.py