# Import 256 bit private key

Tags: private-key, cryptography, private-key-import, private-key-format

Can I import a 256 bit private key in a Wallet (binary format)?
Or do I have to convert it in another format?

Comment: It all depends on the wallet, sometimes it's not possible to directly import a private key, sometimes it uses some specific format (for example WIF for Bitcoin Core). I think you should be more specific or really we can't help much.

Answer (score 1):

`dumpprivkey` in bitcoin core returns [private key](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/private-key) in [WIF](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/wif)

`importprivkey` [adds a private key](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/importprivkey/) (as returned by dumpprivkey) to your wallet.

Private key to WIF: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99101/

Answer (score 1):

Most wallets (and by that, I mean almost all) will not accept a binary 256 bit private key, you will have to convert your 1's and 0's to a WIF format.

There are libraries in python and javascript (and I'm sure other languages too) available that can do this function conversion for you.