# Private key of 44 chars? (old Blockchain.info wallet)

Tags: wallet, private-key, blockchain.info, private-key-export, private-key-format

I'm trying to sweep some coins from an old (blockchain.info) wallet.

I decoded the wallet I have and it gave a private key as a 44 char alphanumeric string starting with 9.

This doesn't seem to be a standard format. I tried to base-64 decode it but it turns out a mess.

Any ideas on how to convert this into a WIF so that other wallets will recognize this?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me know if the Ruby code shared in this answer resolves your issue: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/99101/

Comment: What do you mean by ‘it turns out a mess’ ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "decoded the wallet"? An "alphanumeric string" is often hex, but it can also be Base 64 or base 58 or some other format.  That "decode" process also apparently led you to believe that you got a private key.  Can you point to or describe the process?  I vote to close because it's been a while and the asker hasn't answered Mike D.